# How can you cook a cow with a dispenser and lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

As of 1.6.2, what is the most compact way to cook a cow/pig/chicken with a dispenser and a lava bucket?

Or what is the most compact way to send two fast pulses in order to activate the dispenser and deactivate it fast enough so that the mob is cooked but its drops aren't destroyed by the lava itself?

Comment: You could suspend the lava (ie signs under and around it) above the floor, to achieve the same end. Or have the cow fall through lava to catch fire.

Comment: I have followed this in 1.6.2 and it works great. The drops are kept alive, and only full grown chickens are cooked. Is is the most compact? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfZkooci3Qc

Comment: @ChargingPun, Yeah I know. I asked explicitly a solution with a dispenser and lava because that's what I need in my world. :)

Comment: @ChargingPun Besides, drops can "bounce" up into a lava blade. It's not many, but you still lose 100% efficiency.

Comment: @sevensideddie then you can make the cows fall through the lava instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

**Invisible parts:** Under each orange block is a sticky piston facing up. The left black-framed block is a furnace with 14 items in it (acting as a signal source), and the right black-framed block is the dispenser with a lava bucket.

**How it works:** The input signal comes from the left. The orange block and sticky piston turn the signal into a pulse (a “monostable”, or rising-edge detector) for the dispenser. The right comparator's signal indicates the decreased fullness of the dispenser (empty buckets stack more than full ones), allowing the torch to turn on, which signals the right monostable to produce a second pulse to remove the lava. If a longer burning-in-lava time is desired, lengthen the repeater delay on the right.

It would be possible to simply produce two pulses from the input by delaying the monostable signal; the advantage of this design is that it is self-correcting if the lava is in the wrong state, because the second lava-removing pulse is generated by the dispensing of the lava. However, doing it the other way does have the advantage of needing no quartz.

This design is derived from **[my zombie damager](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102139/how-can-i-bring-zombies-down-to-one-punch-kills-in-minecraft/112244#112244)**, which is a continuous flow system. If you want to have this machine automatically trigger when mobs arrive in it, you could add a tripwire above the lava in the same way as that mechanism does. (The main wiring here is different from there because that machine *removes* the lava, rather than *adding* it, when a mob arrives, but the tripwire can be connected to the input in the same way.)

Finally, note that **chickens are tricky** because they have so little health. Specifically, even with a different pulse circuit built for absolute minimum delay, chickens standing where the lava goes seem to take enough damage to die instantly, burning their items in the lava. However, if the chicken is on a slab underneath the lava (thus being slightly lower), then it sometimes survives long enough to die after the lava disappears, and its drops will sometimes survive even if it dies instantly. (Strange that that makes a difference.) Based on this result, I recommend using something other than lava for chickens.

Tested in Minecraft 1.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

1. Detect animal presence with pressure plate or trip wire
2. Change constant on into a single pulse (about 2-4 ticks)
3. Change pulse into two rapid pulses.

These can be done using two edge detectors and an AND gate.

An Edge detector is basically a NOR gate with both inputs coming from the same line but one with a delay. You can NOR the output with the source line to get an edge detector that only activates when the source turns on. Finally take the output from the NOR gate to the second edge detector. The output from the second edge detector will be two rapid pulses.

Adjust the timing on the first edge detector to increase the time between the pulses. The timing of the second edge detector will adjust the length of the pulses.

I'm not very good at compacting circuits but that's the basic logic behind what you'd want to do.

[Edge Detector](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3n58Az0GMfo) <- used in my design.

Here's my rough design.
[image: Here's my rough schematic]

Answer (score 0):

For chickens at least, I have the feeder chickens sitting on top of a hopper that drops the eggs down into a dispenser wired up with a comparator to determine when it has something and then fire the egg into a space with a halfslab and lava on top of it.  the lava will not harm the egg and a baby chicken is below the level of the halfslab.  When it grows up it will be hit by the lava and the chicken gets cooked with no particular loss of feathers or meat.  Works equally as well replacing with water to get uncooked chicken.

Comment: Screen capture?

Comment: This is basically it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB_C34VFOus

Answer (score -2):

just have a really short timer for like 1 tick on and then one tick off that activates the piston log enough for the lava to come out and back in, but if that happens too fast, just extend the timer by 1 tick every time using multiple repeters